# Inverse Laplace transformation of $\sinh(ks)$

Tags: hyperbolic-functions, inverse-laplace

What is the analytic solution to the following inverse Laplace transformation:

$$ f(t)=L^{-1}{\Big\{ {\sinh(ks)} \Big\}} $$

where $k$ is a constant.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3397208/305862)  a condition under which a Laplace Transform is meaningfull.

Comment: Therefore as $\sinh$ doesn't tend to zero at infinity, your question has no answer.

Comment: Hi @Jean Marie. I just read the post. I understand that the F(s) must tend to zero as the s variable tends to infinity. This means that I can solve for $e^{-cs}$, but not for $e^{cs}$. But if I substitute $c$ to be $-k$, can't I fix that problem that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a function defined by $$ f(t) = c_{1} \, \delta(t + a) + c_{2} \, \delta(t - a). $$ Take the Laplace transform of this function to obtain $$ f(t) \doteqdot c_{1} \, e^{-a \, s} \, H(a) + c_{2} \, e^{a s} \, H(-a), $$ where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside step function. With care of the conditions of the Heaviside function one will find that $$\text{L}^{-1}\{ \sinh(a s) \} = \frac{\delta(t + a) - \delta(t -a)}{2}$$ and if $ a$ and $t$ are positive $$\text{L}^{-1}\{ \sinh(a s) \} = - \frac{\delta(t -a)}{2}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much @Lucippus ! I can proceed further now with my project :D

Comment: I don't understand your two last lines beginning by "And if...